# FMX datasnap send a bitmap as a JPG

Tags: firemonkey, datasnap

in Firemonkey, im currently sending a tbitmap as a stream to a datasnap server - but need to reduce the size and possibly lower the quality prior to sending. I would like to do on-the-fly conversion from the TBitmap to a TJpgImage format as its saved into the TMemoryStream.
if possible - The solution should include a variable for setting the compressionQuality

```
var
  ms:TMemmoryStream;
begin
  ms:=TMemmoryStream.create;

  bmpSend.SaveToStream(msSendPic); //somehow convert bmp to jpg on-the-fly

  sz := msSendPic.size;
  msSendPic.Position :=0;
  svr.setPic(s, sz, msSendPic);
end;
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use TCodecManager and a TBitmapSurface (unit FMX.surfaces)

```
var Surf:TBitmapSurFace  := TBitmapSurface.Create;
try
  Surf.Assign(bmpSend);
  // use the codec to save Surface to stream
  TBitmapCodecManager.SaveToStream(ms,Surf,'.jpg');
finally
   Surf.Free;
end;
```

Comment: for the compression % simply  use
var  saveParams : PBitmapCodecSaveParams;

then
  saveParams.Quality := iQuality; //wanted quality
  TBitmapCodecManager.SaveToStream(msSendPic,Surf,'.jpg',saveParams);